# Unpermitted params error while creating records of grand-child records in grand-parent forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

I have three models `Book_Room`, `Invoice`, and `Bill`. `Invoice` belongs to `BookRoom`, and has many bills. the error is unpermitted params error for :invoice is thrown when i try to create Book Room after ive clearly asked to accept nested params

```
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :book_room
  has_many :bills
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bills
end
```

And `BookRoom` is meant to have only one invoice, but I used `has_many` because the `fields_for` form doesn't render when I use `has_one`.

```
class BookRoom < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer
  has_and_belongs_to_many :rooms
  has_many :invoices
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :invoices
end
```

Here is my `create` action for `invoice` controller:

```
def create
  @booking = BookRoom.find(params[:book_room_id])
  @invoice = @booking.invoice.new(invoice_params)

  if @invoice.save
    redirect_to @invoice, notice: 'Invoice was successfully created.'
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

And here is my form, which is meant to create invoices and bills.

```
<%= f.fields_for :invoice do |i| %>
  <%= i.fields_for :bill do |b| %>
    <%= b.label :price %>
    <%= b.number_field :price %>
    <%= b.hidden_field :type, value: :deposit %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And finally, my `book_room` controller:

```
def create
  @book_room = @customer.book_rooms.new(book_room_params)

  if @book_room.save
    redirect_to @book_room, notice: 'Book room was successfully created.'
  else
    render :new
  end
end
def book_room_params
  params.require(:book_room).permit(:customer_id, :start_date, :end_date, :room_ids=>[], :invoices_attributes => [ :invoice_id, :bills_attributes => [:price, :type] ])
end
```

When I try to create a book room with bill records, it throws an error of unpermitted params invoice. If there is a way to get the form to render on `has_one` relationship, I will appreciate it.

Comment: What is the error? Update the question with it.

Comment: updated my question.. was there some sort of unpermitted question revamp was done when i submitted and the question was cut out

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to `has_one :invoice` association - `fields_for` can work with it, but you need to build association first with `@book_room.build_invoice` in `BookRoomController#new` controller action.

Then you can fix `book_room_params` - change `invoices_attributes` key to singular `invoice_attributes`.

Comment: I have added this and still doesnt display the form.. but if i pluralise from f.fields :invoice to :invoices it shows the form.. but on :invoice it doesnt